# Loop complexity with i^k

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Consider this loop (`k` - a positive integer number):

```
// i^k as in i raised to the power of k
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i = i^k) {
    // some O(1) expressions or statements
}
```

Why this run for `log_k(log(n))` times?

Comment: what is 'i^k'? bitwise?

Comment: Do you mean `i = i^k`? Just `i^k` as an iteration step does nothing.

Comment: i mean i=i^k i corrected the post

Comment: You should change `i=i^k` to `i=pow(i,k)` or `i=i**k` as `^` is generally used to denote bitwise xor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is essentially: how many times will we need to raise *2* to the power of *k* until it is larger than [image: n = 2^{log_2(n)}].

Note that [image: (2^k)^k = 2^{k*k}], so continuing to raise it (by *k*) *t* times results in [image: 2^{(k^t)}].

Now let's solve: [image: 2^{(k^t)} > 2^{log_2(n)}]. Same as asking: [image: k^t > log_2(n)]. Take a [image: log_k] from both sides and finally get: [image: t > log_k (log_2 (n))].

Comment: @Anatolii, I've added some clarification... hope it's clearer now..

Answer (score 0):

In your question we want to know how many time the for loop is passed so we have to find the x of this eq:  `2^x^k=2^k^x= n` so we have `x^k = log(n)` than : `x = logk(log(n))`.

Comment: StackOverflow, unlike Math, does not offer LaTeX formatting/rendering.